# Ratchet PHP zeromq fallback to older browsers

Tags: php, compatibility, zeromq, fallback, ratchet

Following this instruction http://socketo.me/docs/push I had this working.

However, I'd like my service to be compatible with older browsers as well (IE 8 etc), so I need to use a flash fallback (like web_socket.js or similar) to do this:

```
function initPull() {
    var conn = new ab.Session(

        // The host (our Ratchet WebSocket server) to
        'ws://'+PUSH_SOCKET_SERVER+':'+PUSH_SOCKET_PORT+'/',

        // Once the connection has been established
        function() {            
            conn.subscribe(TOPIC_PREFIX+rID, function(topic, data) {

                //Trigger action
                aTrigger(data);
            });
        },

        // When the connection is closed
        function() {            
            console.warn('WebSocket connection closed');
        },

        // Additional parameters, we're ignoring the WAMP sub-protocol for older browsers
        {
            'skipSubprotocolCheck': true
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Ratchet supports [web-socket-js](https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js), which is a natural polyfill. The ZMQ code is on the server side and will still be executed if your client is using native WebSockets or the Flash polyfill.

Keep your code from the Push tutorial as is, add web-socket-js code to your client and then see the code from the [FlashPolicy component](http://socketo.me/docs/flash).

For a bit more involved example, see [this example](https://github.com/cboden/Ratchet-examples/blob/master/bin/website-chatroom.php#L63) on how to server Flash Policy files without having to run two separate processes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have done just what you suggested. The idea is to combine chat server with push messages. This all works except flash polyfill. Here is my server code:

```
//This is a server to handle both WAMP chat messages and PUSH messages
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Server\FlashPolicy;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use Ratchet\Wamp\ServerProtocol;

use React\EventLoop\Factory;
use React\Socket\Server as Reactor;
use React\ZMQ\Context;

use Ratchet\Wamp\WampServer;
use Ratchet\Cookbook\OpenPubSub;
use Ratchet\Website\PortLogger;
use Ratchet\Cookbook\NullComponent;
use Ratchet\Cookbook\MessageLogger;
use Ratchet\Push\Pusher;


use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;


// Composer: The greatest thing since sliced bread
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

// Setup logging
$stdout = new StreamHandler('php://stdout');
$logout = new Logger('SockOut');
$login  = new Logger('Sock-In');
$login->pushHandler($stdout);
$logout->pushHandler($stdout);

// The all mighty event loop
$loop = Factory::create();

// This little thing is to check for connectivity...
// As a case study, when people connect on port 80, we're having them
//  also connect on port 9000 and increment a counter if they connect.
// Later, we can publish the results and find out if WebSockets over 
//  a port other than 80 is viable (theory is blocked by firewalls).
$context = new Context($loop);
$push = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH);
$push->connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:8080');

// Setup our Ratchet ChatRoom application
$webSock = new Reactor($loop);
$webSock->listen(8080, '0.0.0.0');
$webServer = new IoServer(           // Basic I/O with clients, aww yeah
    new WsServer(                    // Boom! WebSockets
        new PortLogger($push, 80,    // Compare vs the almost over 9000 conns
            new MessageLogger(       // Log events in case of "oh noes"
              new WampServer(
                new OpenPubSub
              )
              , $login
              , $logout
            )
        )
    )
  , $webSock
);

// Allow Flash sockets (Internet Explorer) to connect to our app
$flashSock = new Reactor($loop);
$flashSock->listen(843, '0.0.0.0');
$policy = new FlashPolicy;
$policy->addAllowedAccess('*', 80);
$policy->addAllowedAccess('*', 8080);
$policy->addAllowedAccess('*', 8081);
$webServer = new IoServer($policy, $flashSock);

$logSock = new Reactor($loop);
$logSock->listen(9000, '0.0.0.0');
$zLogger = new IoServer(
    new WsServer(
      new MessageLogger(
        new PortLogger($push, 9000, new NullComponent)
        )
    )
  , $logSock
);


$pusher = new Pusher;

// Listen for the web server to make a ZeroMQ push after an ajax request
$context = new React\ZMQ\Context($loop);
$pull = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);
$pull->bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555'); // Binding to 127.0.0.1 means the only client that can connect is itself
$pull->on('message', array($pusher, 'onMsg'));

// Set up our WebSocket server for clients wanting real-time updates
$webSock = new React\Socket\Server($loop);
$webSock->listen(8081, '0.0.0.0'); // Binding to 0.0.0.0 means remotes can connect
$webServer = new Ratchet\Server\IoServer(
    new Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer(
        new MessageLogger(
          new Ratchet\Wamp\WampServer(
              $pusher
          )
        )
    ),
    $webSock
);    

// GO GO GO!
echo "[".Date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."] VPCserver started...\n";
$loop->run();
```